# Mapping a custom attribute to a group

Tags: attributes, okta

I'm trying to map a custom SAML attribute used by another app to a group. Essentially we have 3 roles and the idea is to have 3 AD groups that'll be tied with each role.

Per the answer in [Okta Group Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072908/okta-group-attributes), I see that it's not directly possible.

What I've tried per the suggestion is to set a custom profile mapping for the application with nested ternary operators to mimic an 3 if statements to set an attribute. However, while the ternary operators work, getting the mapping to work when creating the 'Attribute Statements' portion does not.

How else can I go about this? I'd prefer not to create 3 apps for 3 different roles if possible.

Answer (score 0):

In scenarios like this i'll have Okta send the group(s) the user is a member of through as a custom attribute.

Within the SAML app configuration this option presents itself as Group Name and Group filter. (Application -> General Tab -> App Settings)

I'll create groups that will be representative of a 'role' i want the member user to have in the downsteam app (SP) and then apply a group filter to only include those groups.

App1.Roleabc
App1.Roleefg
App1.Rolehij

Group Filter: App1.*
Group Name: Groups

The group "name" will be the name of the attribute used in the assertion and a saml assertion based on those values would look something along the lines of this:

```
<saml2p:Response>
    ...
    <saml2:Assertion>"
        ...
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID>me@mydomain.tld</saml2:NameID>
            ...
        </saml2:Subject>
        ...
        <saml2:AttributeStatement>
            <saml2:Attribute Name="arbitraryAttribut">
                <saml2:AttributeValue> meaningfulValue </saml2:AttributeValue>
            </saml2:Attribute>
            <saml2:Attribute Name="Groups">
                <saml2:AttributeValue> App1.Roleabc </saml2:AttributeValue>
                <saml2:AttributeValue> App1.Rolehij </saml2:AttributeValue>
            </saml2:Attribute>
        </saml2:AttributeStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Comment: So in this case, the role would have to be named the exact same way in AD, correct? Assuming I understand you correctly.

I thought about something like this, e.g. renaming the AD group so that "Okta-" would be omitted from the group name and then doing a group filter based on whatever group that user is in.

Comment: Yes with this method the value that is sent in the SAML assertion is going to be the full group name as defined in AD (and subsequently Okta).